# Read file line by line and do regex replace

Tags: c#, regex, file-io, scalability

I've written a program that reads a text file into a variable, does a regex replace on the text, and writes it back to the file. Obviously this is not scalable for large text files; I want to be able to read the text file line-by-line and do a regex replace for a desired pattern.

Here is my non-scalable code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("names.txt");
    string pattern = "Ali";
    string rep = "Tyson";

    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    fileContents = rgx.Replace(fileContents, rep);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("names.txt", fileContents);}
```

I know how to use StreamReader for reading a file line-by-line but when I tried nest StreamWriter inside of StreamReader so I could write to the file while searching line-by-line I ran into an unhandled exception error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: does it have to be `RegEx.Replace` are you familiar with `string.Replace()` method..? can you not do the following 
`var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("names.txt");`
`fileContents = fileContents.Replace("Ali", "Tyson");`

Comment: I hope this goes without saying... Are you writing to a different file than you're reading from?

Comment: I used that pattern as a simple example, I actually have regex strings for replacing version numbers and dates in files. Can replace handle regex strings?

Comment: I want to read and write to the same file, is that possible in C#? I have Ruby and Python scripts that can do this, I just wanted to see if I could do it in C#.

Comment: If what you want is to use a StreamReader, try it for yourself first and then show us what you've tried, along with a description of why it's not working for you. There are plenty of examples on the net if you search properly.

Comment: please express all relevant issues pertaining to your question `I ran into an unhandled exception error.` so what is the Exception / Error

Comment: I just said StreamReader because that's how I've read line-by-line in files before, if there's another way to do it I'm all ears

Comment: The unhandled exception occurred when it got to the StreamWriter line and said "The file cannot be accessed because it is being used by another process" presumably because StreamReader was currently reading the file

Comment: Are you saying you want to read a file line-by-line and do a regex replace in-line (modifying the same stream you're reading)?  If so, don't do that.  Instead, read from one file, writing the results to another, and finally do a file copy/rename to overwrite the original.

Comment: Is there a way to simultaneously read and write to a file?

Comment: @StewC, yes, there is. The FileAccess flag is governs that in [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s67691sb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Comment: There is, but you don't want to do that because if you make a mistake or get an error your data will be permanently destroyed. If you want to make a one-pass replacement of text in a large file, consult [Large single-file parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247952/).

Comment: Ok that works. Yes I was hoping to do a replace in-line. I was hoping I'd be able to not have to do the file copy/rename/overwrite part

Comment: @StewC, yes, you can use a `FileStream` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but it won't be simple because the size of the matched text won't necessarily match the size of the replacement text, meaning you'd be repeatedly rewriting the file from the top down as you work your way line by line through it.  Better to just use two files, one for reading and one for writing.

Comment: @StewC, I'm not sure how would in-line replace work for case when for example short line would get replaced with much longer one ...

Comment: @alex.b The version numbers and dates I would be replacing are always in the same format i.e. dates are always xx/xx/xxxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this,

```
using (var input = File.OpenText("input.txt"))
using (var output = new StreamWriter("output.txt")) {
  string line;
  while (null != (line = input.ReadLine()) {
     // Apply regex to line before writing to new outpu file
     output.WriteLine(line);
  }
}
```

Once you finish reading and writing all lines to output.txt you could replace input.txt with output.txt.

Comment: This will work. Even though there's the extra step of replacing the input file with the output one, it looks like this is the easiest way of performing this task in C#. Thanks.

Comment: You can do this as a one-liner: `File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", File.ReadLines("input.txt").Select(l => rgx.Replace(l, rep)));`