# Console.WriteLine is blank

Tags: c#, .net, console

I have a strange problem.  I wrote a .net 2.0 console application running on `Windows Server 2008 R2` that processes a file that's passed in via `args` When I run it by hand and pass in a file, I don't get an output. Nothing.  No errors or exception of any kind.  Event log is clear.  I would expect that I get some output from the exe.  I also have a `Console.WriteLine` in my `catch` statement.  But again, no output whatsoever.  Any ideas why?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace RTDXCentralFileTransmit
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                if (args.Length < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File name is required");
                    logit("File name is required");
                    return;
                }
                string filename = args[0];

                Console.WriteLine("Now doing " + filename);
                logit("Now doing " + filename);

                if (!File.Exists(filename))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File " + filename + " does not exists.  Exiting.");
                    logit("File " + filename + " does not exists.  Exiting.");
                    File.WriteAllText("Error.txt", "File " + filename + " does not exists.  Exiting.");
                    return;
                }

                string fileplain = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                string file64 = EncodeTo64(fileplain);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file64))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File " + filename + " is empty.  Exiting");
                    logit("File " + filename + " is empty.  Exiting");
                    File.WriteAllText("Error.txt", "File " + filename + " is empty.  Exiting");
                    return;
                }

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);

                com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.api.Dispatch dis = new com.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.api.Dispatch();
                com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.api.FunnelResult fr = dis.Funnel(file64, fi.Name);

                if (fr.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Success! " + fr.Result);
                    logit("Success!  Response from the server: " + fr.Result);
                    File.WriteAllText("Success.txt", fr.Result);
                    return;
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed!! " + fr.Result);
                    logit("Failed!! " + fr.Result);
                    File.WriteAllText("Error.txt", "Transmission Failed! " + fr.Result);
                }
                logit("Exiting for " + filename);
                Environment.Exit(0);

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error. " + e.ToString());
                return;
            }

        }

        static void logit (string s)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("FileTransmit.log",DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + s + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
        {
            byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
                  = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
            string returnValue
                  = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a `try` - is there perhaps a `catch` here that is swallowing an exception? and what is `logit`?

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, verifiable example that shows the behavior. Or, better yet, single-step the program in your debugger. That should reveal the error pretty quickly.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have to say that some of the files that is passed in are large in terms of size.  But not sure how is that have to do with Console.WriteLine not printing anything.  Is there something in the registry (or somewhere) that would throttle how big of a file .net can process?  The input file is a plain text file which I convert it to Base64 before I post it to a remote server.  But that's waaay...pass the Console.WriteLine.

Comment: @JimMischel  Works in the debugger when I step through it.  It doesn't work in the /debug directory when I run it by hand in the console window.

Comment: @Zuzlx in .net the largest byte[] or string allowed is a little under 2 GiB; you can process much larger files than that, but not if you try to read them all at once. But since you don't show any *file read* code...

Comment: The whole code is attached.  Again, this is .net 2.0

Comment: Try publishing it as self-contained app?

Comment: @Marc is right; `ReadAllText` and `WriteAllText` are the wrong way for large files. Use [`Streams`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247952/).

Comment: @zaitsman Darn thing was a windows application in the settings.  Thanks for the tip!!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The issue was between the chair and the computer.

The project that I cloned, even though it had tons of Console.WriteLine, it was actually was being built as `Windows Application.`  That explains why we have no output for the `Console.WriteLine.`

Since it was being build as `windows application`, the console doesn't wait for the program to finish.  It returns right away - which totally threw me off seeing that many console.writelines. However, the program is still running and, with a large file, it takes a while to post it to the remote server.  After waiting a minute or two all of 10 MB file was transmitted successfully as it was indicated in the logs.