# C# lightweight skeleton parse file

Tags: c#, regex, file, parsing

I have a file with format similar to

```
{1:[...]}{2:[X:11][Y:78][]...}{3:[...]}{4:[...]}{5:
[]
[]
...
[]}$
{1:[...]}{2:[X:43][Y:13][]...}{3:[...]}{4:[...]}{5:
[]
[]
...
[]}$
...
```

The ellipsis indicates many repeating structures or many repeating lines.

So file is made up of segments with identical format separated by pipe char.

What is the optimal way to extract just the values of X for each segment ? so we avoid loading the entire file into memory.  Optimal in space and time. Probably this means avoiding loading entire file into memory. Possibly we could read each line and regex to match `{2:[X:nn][` and extract `nn` but that's a small fraction of lines.

But perhaps there's a better way ?

Comment: I would read file with StreamReader one line at a time to avoid putting entire file into memory. It looks like you just need to parse lines starting with the curly bracket.  Then extract X values from line using Regex.

Comment: You could read each character, storing which element of the hierarchy you are currently in, and [extracting only the desired values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247952/). The benefit of doing this is it doesn't mater how long each line is, and this will tell you if your data is invalid.

Comment: @jdweng `File.ReadLines` returns an `Enumerable`, and will have the same effect as `StreamReader`

Comment: If these are large files and speed is a concern, i would just parse this with `fixed(char* p = yourLine)` it will out perform regex. however if speed is not a concern regex will be more succinct and manageable

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this,

**Given**

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\Test.txt");
```

***Note** :  `File.ReadLines` return an `Enumerbale`, so it will load each line lazily*

---

**Option 1** : Regex using a *Positive Look-behind* and the pattern `(?<=2:\[X:)\d+`

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   var match = Regex.Match(line,@"(?<=2:\[X:)\d+");
   if(match.Success)
      Console.WriteLine(match.Value);  
}
```

**Option 2** : Simple `string.Split`

```
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   var results = line.Split(new[] { "2:[X:", "][Y:" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   if(results.Length>1)
      Console.WriteLine(results[1]);
}
```

**Option 3** :  "Possibly" a more performant approach, using *Pointers* `fixed` and `unsafe`

```
public static unsafe (bool found, int value) ParseLine(string line)
{
   const string prefix = "2:[X:"; 
   fixed (char* pLine = line,pPrefix = prefix)
   {
 
      var pLen = line.Length + pLine;
      var found = false;
      var result = 0;
      var i = 0;
      for (char* p = pLine ,pP = pPrefix; p < pLen; p++)
      {
         if (!found )
         {
            if( *p == *(pP+i)) i++;
            if( i ==prefix.Length) found = true;
            continue;
         }
         
         if (*p < '0' || *p > '9')
            break;

         result = result * 10 + *p - '0';

 
      }

      return (found, result);
   }
}
    
...

var results = File.ReadLines(@"D:\Test.txt")
                  .Select(ParseLine)
                  .Where(result => result.found)
                  .Select(result => result.value);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

---

***Note** : this is not about regex bashing, just different approaches.*

I haven't benchedmarked this, however my suspicion is the *Pointers* will be the fastest, `split` will come next, and *Regex* will possibly be the slowest (even if using compiled), however it is the most readable and maintainable and also robust approach (which is why i put it first)

## Benchmarks

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|  Method  |    Mean    |   Error   |  StdDev   |
+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| RegEx    | 3,358.3 us | 65.169 us | 66.923 us |
| Split    | 1,980.9 us | 38.440 us | 48.614 us |
| Pointers | 287.4 us   | 4.396 us  | 4.112 us  |
+----------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Test Code**

```
public class Test
{
   private Regex _regex;

   private string[] data;

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void Setup()
   {
      _regex = new Regex(@"(?<=2:\[X:)\d+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

      data = File.ReadLines(@"D:\Test3.txt")
                 .ToArray();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<int> RegEx()
   {
      return data.Select(line => _regex.Match(line))
                 .Where(x => x.Success)
                 .Select(match => int.Parse(match.Value))
                 .ToList();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<int> Split()
   {
      return data.Select(line => line.Split(new[] { "2:[X:", "][Y:" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                 .Where(results => results.Length > 1)
                 .Select(results => int.Parse(results[1]))
                 .ToList();
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public List<int> Pointers()
   {
      return data.Select(ParseLine)
                 .Where(result => result.found)
                 .Select(result => result.value)
                 .ToList();
   }

   public static unsafe (bool found, int value) ParseLine(string line)
   {
      const string prefix = "2:[X:"; 
      fixed (char* pLine = line,pPrefix = prefix)
      {
    
         var pLen = line.Length + pLine;
         var found = false;
         var result = 0;
         var i = 0;
         for (char* p = pLine ,pP = pPrefix; p < pLen; p++)
         {
            if (!found )
            {
               if( *p == *(pP+i)) i++;
               if( i ==prefix.Length) found = true;
               continue;
            }
            
            if (*p < '0' || *p > '9')
               break;

            result = result * 10 + *p - '0';

    
         }

         return (found, result);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Much more efficient to use if(line.StartsWith("{")) before using Regex.

Comment: @jdweng yeah good point, the same with all of them really too

Comment: `x:` can appear in other block-types than `2:` , however I am only interested in `X:` within the `2:` block.