# Alternative to StreamReader.ReadLine(filepath) to avoid running out of memory?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, streamreader, denial-of-service

Consider the following:

```
using (var fs = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
    while (!fs.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = fs.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

If filepath was a file with very long lines of characters (many characters between line feeds), it could cause the server to run out of memory on one of the ReadLine() calls.  This is a potential Denial of Service vector.

Are there any C# classes that mitigate this issue?  I am creating a new class that inherits StreamReader and uses the StreamReader.ReadBlock() method to read a finite block of characters, but then I have to handle parsing the block by line feeds to be able to return the lines from the file.  I would like to use some Framework class to do the same if one exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Extremely Large Single-Line File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247952/).

Comment: 1. the real problem should lie some where else(where you use those lines). 2. try move the type definition of string line **out** of for loop.

Comment: What do you want to happen with such a line? Throw an exception, read it in multiple chunks, truncate it?

Comment: What is the typical file size?

Comment: The question depends on line length and memory size.

Comment: I ended up using ReadBlock() method instead of ReadLine() method.  But I had to handle parsing each line myself.  I read an arbitrary, sufficiently large block (but not so large as to deplete memory) and store it in an in-memory buffer and return the lines from the buffer.  When buffer is empty, I read another block.

Answer (score 0):

You van read blocks, you only gotta keep track of where you at

```
            char[] buffer = new char[24];

            while (!r.EndOfStream)
            {
                bytesRead = r.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```